# Axios Get returns an empty array on the server but works fine in local [d3 application in react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, axios

I am building a scatter graph using `d3` in my `react` application.

I have the following code where I fetch some data when a user click on a circle (or dot) in the scatter graph, and display the data in a tooltip. I am using `axios` to fetch the data. The code works fine in the localhost (although I fetch the data from the same online database), and the data is fetched and then displayed.

However, on the server, the `axios.get()` method returns an empty array (`[]`) and nothing is displayed. The call to fetch the data is successful (`http 200`). I wonder why it works this way on the server but it works fine in the local. The data is fetched from the same database.

Any ideas?

```
useEffect(() => {

    chart.selectAll('dot').data(discussionPostHistory).enter().append('circle').attr('r', 5)
        .attr('cx', function (d: any) { return xScale(d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.dateCreated)) + 30; })
        .attr('cy', function (d: any) { return yScale3(d["numberOfDiscussionPosts"]) })  
        .on("click", function (this: any, d: any) {
         axios.get('api/CommentGeneral/FetchDailyComments',
             {
                 params: {
                     id: props.id,
                 }
             })
             .then(response => {
                        const comments = new schema.Entity("comments");
                        const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [comments]);

                        var commentsData = normalizedData.entities.comments;
                        var commentIds = normalizedData.result;

                        //the rest of the code to build the tooltip
                        //using commentsData and commentIds

                    })
     })        
}, [props.rubricItemId, props.analyticsData])
```

Comment: Does your API call also return `[]` (in the network tab of the devtools)?

Comment: @thibautg yes. I check the response in the devtools of the browser.

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your backend which has data on localhost but returns an empty array on the server. Are you sure that data is the same on the server than on localhost, and that the server's API is working correctly? It does not seem to be a frontend issue.

Comment: @thibautg I thought this might be a `premise` issue but you are right, the problem is different. I will reformulate the content and make a new post. thanks!